# How to use '!!' (double exclamation) in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is the scenario: Sometimes I want to open a list of files using vim. That list of files is output of a command. So I can type `vim $(!!)` and open those files after running that command.

Is it possible to define an alias for this vim command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alias vl='vim $(fc -s)'` should do what you request